# Read from file word by word with spaces in C

Tags: c, file

The `input` data in the `text` file are as follow:

```
Mike     107        Europe             6798  
Steve    023        New York           2588
Adam     057        South Town         1902
Adam     124        Asia               5555
```

The data separated with `whitespace`

`C code` to read data from file is:

```
char name[30];
int code;
char local[30];
int id;


while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %[^ ] %d", name, &code, local, &id) != EOF){

    printf("%s-%d-%s-%d\n", name, code, local, id);
}
```

The problem with my code is that always read one word at time for `local` the output of my print is:

```
Mike     107        Europe             6798  
Steve    023        New                2588
Adam     057        South              1902
Adam     124        Asia               5555
```

`New York` and `South Town` are truncated. How do I fix that ?

Comment: The format `%[^ ]` will work exactly like `%s`, i.e. read until the next space. I recommend you [read whole lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then try to extract the field using some other way.

Comment: It seems that in this data space is not a true delimiter, are you using column number to delimit the fields or TAB characters perhaps.  If you possibly have a mix of TAB and SPC then you really have a problem of ambiguous delimiters.

Comment: I don't believe you when you claim that you will get the number 2588 there. No, it will be the number from the previous line.

Comment: @kerma Are you sure your input file is separated with spaces, not with tabs?

Comment: @KamilCuk only spaces no tabs

Comment: @Clifford thanks for solution, but It did NOT work, same output ?!!

Comment: @Clifford's answer is one way to go. Alternatively, if you are on a POSIX-compatible system you might use the [POSIX regular expressions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) functions to parse lines, or if you want to be completely cross-platform, an external library like [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/) might be useful.

Comment: @G.Sliepen only c, I am trying to read data from file, the separator is whitespaces. not tabs. and only the probelm reading location, other data read correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to want it both ways - to use space as a delimiter and also as content.  It is at best an ambiguous design decision and CSV might be a better solution.  However you can use probably assumptions about the data content that will at least in the example input solve the problem.

Assuming the `local` column cannot contain digit characters, then:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %d %[^0123456789\t] %d", name, &code, local, &id)
```

I have included `\t` (TAB) to be sure that does not trip it up.  The effect of this however is that the `local` includes all the trailing spaces.  You could trim them thus:

```
for( int i = strlen(local) - 1; local[i] == ' '; i-- )
{
    local[i] = 0 ;
}
```

Alternatively you might read the entire line and process it such that a single space is not a delimiter and >1 space or TAB is.  Or if you can guarantee no TABs you could extract the fields data by column number, but it all gets rather fiddly:

```
    while( fgets( line, sizeof(line), fp ) != NULL )
    {
        line[NAME_COL-1] = 0 ;
        line[CODE_COL-1] = 0 ;
        line[ID_COL-1] = 0 ;
        sscanf(&s[NAME_COL], "%s", name) ;
        sscanf(&s[CODE_COL], "%d", &code) ;
        sscanf(&s[LOCAL_COL], "%s", local) ;
        sscanf(&s[ID_COL], "%d", &id) ;
        for( int i = strlen(local) - 1; local[i] == ' '; i-- )
        {
            local[i] = 0 ;
        }
        printf("%s-%d-%s-%d\n", name, code, local, id);
    }
```

Comment: @G.Sliepen what do u mean? I have tested this solution, but did not work, same output !?

Comment: @G.Sliepen - Fixed - problem is it then includes all the trailing spaces in `local`.  Working in on it.

Comment: @G.Sliepen : Simplest solution seems to be to strip the trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix that ?

You could read up until two consecutive spaces. You would have to implement such logic yourself, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char input[] =
    "Mike     107        Europe             6798  \n"
    "Steve    023        New York           2588\n"
    "Adam     057        South Town         1902\n"
    "Adam     124        Asia               5555\n"
    ;

int main() {
    FILE *in = fmemopen((char*)input, sizeof(input) - 1, "r");

    char name[30];
    int code;
    char local[30];
    int id;

    char line[250];
    int localstart;
    const char *localend;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%s%d %n", name, &code, &localstart) != 2) break;
        localend = strstr(line + localstart, "  ");
        if (localend == NULL) break;
        const size_t locallen = localend - (line + localstart);
        memcpy(local, line + localstart, locallen);
        local[locallen] = '\0';
        if (sscanf(line + locallen, "%d", &id) != 1) break;

        printf("%s-%d-%s-%d\n", name, code, local, id);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could for example: read the whole line and inspect if from the back. The 3rd column starts after spaces after 2nd column and before spaces before 4th column.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char input[] =
    "Mike     107        Europe             6798  \n"
    "Steve    023        New York           2588\n"
    "Adam     057        South Town         1902\n"
    "Adam     124        Asia               5555\n"
    ;

int main() {
    FILE *in = fmemopen((char*)input, sizeof(input) - 1, "r");

    char name[30];
    int code;
    char local[30];
    int id;

    char line[250];
    int localstart;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%s%d %n", name, &code, &localstart) != 2) break;
        const char *end = line + strlen(line) - 1;
        // ignore trailing spaces
        while (end != line && isspace(*end)) end--;
        // jump over last digit
        while (end != line && isdigit(*end)) end--;
        // scan the last digit
        if (sscanf(end + 1, "%d", &id) != 1) break;
        // rewind spaces
        while (end != line && isspace(*end)) end--;
        // at end + 1 ends 'local' column
        const char *localend = end + 1;
        const size_t locallen = localend - (line + localstart);
        memcpy(local, line + localstart, locallen);
        local[locallen] = '\0';

        printf("%s-%d-%s-%d\n", name, code, local, id);
    }
}
```

The `fmemopen` function is available on linux that I used for testing here - it may not be available on windows.